# Where are VPN configuration files imported by Network Manager saved?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've imported an OpenVPN configuration file that behaves differently when trying to connect from Network Manager and command line. I would like to see what the imported configuration file looks like.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**12.04 onwards**

Connection information is stored in the directory:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Note: This directory stores other connection information such as wifi connections.

**Pre 12.04**

In Kubuntu, `network-manager-openvpn-kde` saves its profiles to:

```
~/.kde/share/apps/networkmanagement/connections/
```

In Ubuntu, `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` saves its profiles to:

```
~/.gconf/system/networking/connections/
```

(VPN settings are in ~/.gconf/system/networking/connections/*/vpn/%gconf.xml)

Comment: Isn't there a way to have it directly use .conf files?

Comment: There is, but it circumvents the network-manager. Place the file in `/etc/openvpn/`. Make sure it has a `.conf` suffix, the init script at `/etc/init.d/openvpn` searches for such files. The VPN will be started at boot time. To disable this, edit `/etc/default/openvpn` uncomment the `AUTOSTART=none` line. I'm doing it this way because the `network-manager-openvpn` is too limited, I cannot run script after connection for example. To start OpenVPN with your configuration file `client.conf`, run `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start client`. To stop it, run `/etc/init.d/openvpn stop client`.

Comment: It seems this answer is no longer up-to-date as of Ubuntu 12.04. I have a couple VPNs configured through Network Manager in 12.04 using network-manager-openvpn-gnome, but there is no ~/.gconf/system directory. Anyone know where those files might live nowadays?

Comment: @CarlMeyer Try importing and run the command `find ~ -mmin -3 -ls` to find all modified files in the last 3 minutes.

Comment: I found a whole slew of files modified, but none of them look like openvpn kind of things.

Comment: Turns out they are stored in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ (even when they aren't shared with everyone)

Comment: Can a file just be added to ```/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/```, or are there other places where this data is redundantly stored?

Comment: @snapfractalpop Network Manager reads network profiles from `/etc/NetworkManager/` only. Though there are other locations where network information can be stored (such as `/etc/network/`), or `/etc/sysconfig/` depending on the loaded plugins in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (see the manual page of `NetworkManager.conf`).

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong in Uburnu 23.10. The file is not at any of these locations.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in Ubuntu 12.04 and later the config settings are stored in  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections -- except, when someone didn't migrate the connection information out of an older .conf file and continued using that .conf file instead. In that case, the settings are in /home/USER/.gcm/gcm.conf