# Where is OpenVPN's client configuration from Network-manager's OpenVPN plugin?

Tags: networking, network-manager, configuration, vpn, openvpn

I know how to write and when to put OpenVPN's config files for clients but I would like to be able to see the config files generated by `network-manager-openvpn` plugin. (For instance to change logging verbosity)

Namely this one:

[image]

Any idea where are they stored ?

Comment: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29086/where-are-vpn-configuration-files-imported-by-network-manager-saved). Although, it looks like the vpn configs are in /etc/NetworkManager/VPN

Comment: @Zetrocker In 13.10 where I have been looking for this I have it under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyVPN_connection`. You can post an answer I will accept it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29086/where-are-vpn-configuration-files-imported-by-network-manager-saved) in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Although, it looks like the VPN configs are in `/etc/NetworkManager/VPN`

Answer (score 0):

I think your client configuration file is located at `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`.

The following command should allow access:

```
sudo gedit /etc/openvpn/client.conf
```

Good luck.

Comment: NetworkManager's configuration for OpenVPN is not stored in /etc/openvpn.